# Dotfuscator doesn't support Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I tested Dotfuscator with some of my DLLs written in C#.
It seemed it works really well on .NET environment, so this time I tried them with Unity3D. Those simple DLLs were just coded only with simple standard C# classes and methods, no reflection, no LINQ, no other custom or 3rd party APIs including Unity's. But failed to make them work in my Unity3d project, while original pure DLLs which aren't obfuscated were working fine.
After struggling for a few hours, I decided to test with new simple projects. Below is all I got in C#, there are no other code, no other references at all.

```
[System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Feature = "renaming", Exclude = true)]
public class Class1
{
    [System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Feature = "renaming", Exclude = true)]
    public static int Get()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

After compiling this to DLL, I put it in an EMPTY project on Unity3D Editor and played, and it worked well. But when I gave another try after obfuscating the DLL with Dotfuscator, it stopped saying "**InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in Class1:Get (): IL_000c: pop**".

As you can see above, I added attributes which prevent the code from being renamed, and of course, I could see in Reflector, the name of both class and method weren't actually renamed.

Yesterday I newly registered and downloaded the evaluation version of the latest Dotfuscator Professional Edition 4.21.0 from PreEmptive's site. I compiled both on Visual Studio 2008 and 2015 with .NET 3.5, also tried with all different Solution Platforms. The version of Unity is 5.3.4f1.

My guess now is Dotfuscator only works with MSIL, not Mono 2.X which Unity3D internally uses.

Am I right? Is there anyone using Dotfuscator with Unity3D or Mono well?

[EDIT]
I checked IL code using ILDasm, don't understand what's going on, but interesting to see a bunch of code is modified.

**Before applying Dotfuscator**

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  Get() cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 02 00 54 0E 07 46 65 61 74 75 72 65 08 72   // ....T..Feature.r
                                                                                      65 6E 61 6D 69 6E 67 54 02 07 45 78 63 6C 75 64   // enamingT..Exclud
                                                                                      65 01 )                                           // e.
  // Code Size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4     0x75bcd15
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Class1::Get
```

**After applying Dotfuscator**

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  Get() cil managed
{
  // Code Size       127 (0x7f)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (int32 V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4     0x993
  IL_0005:  stloc      V_0
  IL_0009:  ldloca     V_0
  IL_000d:  ldind.i4
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4     0x993
  IL_0013:  stloc      V_0
  IL_0017:  ldloca     V_0
  IL_001b:  ldind.i4
  IL_001c:  ceq
  IL_001e:  switch     ( 
                        IL_002f,
                        IL_004c,
                        IL_002f)
  IL_002f:  br.s       IL_003e
  IL_0031:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0032:  stloc      V_0
  IL_0036:  ldloca     V_0
  IL_003a:  ldind.i4
  IL_003b:  pop
  IL_003c:  br.s       IL_004a
  IL_003e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_003f:  stloc      V_0
  IL_0043:  ldloca     V_0
  IL_0047:  ldind.i4
  IL_0048:  br.s       IL_003b
  IL_004a:  nop
  IL_004b:  nop
  IL_004c:  ldc.i4     0x1
  IL_0051:  stloc      V_0
  IL_0055:  ldloca     V_0
  IL_0059:  ldind.i4
  IL_005a:  br.s       IL_0068
  IL_005c:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_005d:  stloc      V_0
  IL_0061:  ldloca     V_0
  IL_0065:  ldind.i4
  IL_0066:  br.s       IL_0068
  IL_0068:  brfalse.s  IL_006a
  IL_006a:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_006b:  stloc      V_0
  IL_006f:  ldloca     V_0
  IL_0073:  ldind.i4
  IL_0074:  brfalse    IL_0079
  IL_0079:  ldc.i4     0x75bcd15
  IL_007e:  ret
} // end of method Class1::Get
```

Comment: Did you try creating in MonoDevelop (goes with Unity) new Mono 2 project, and test you dlls there? If it will work, the problem is with Unity if not, the problem is with Mono and/or Mono version unity uses.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Thanks. As you said, I think it's worth trying and will check it when I get back home :) BTW, Mono 2.X version is available now? Unity uses old version of Mono, so it maybe different if not..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As of version 6.0, Dotfuscator Professional no longer supports Unity. (See [changelog for 6.0.0-beta](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/dotfuscator-pro-change-log/1176)). It continues to support Mono. The original answer follows.

---

Yes, Dotfuscator Professional Edition supports Mono and Unity. The reason you're seeing differences in the IL is due to the *Control Flow* obfuscation that Professional Edition provides. This is a distinct from the *Renaming* feature from which you have excluded your identifiers.

By default, Dotfuscator uses as many Control Flow transforms as it can get away with on the .NET Framework (i.e., Microsoft's implementation). **However, some of these transforms are not compatible with Mono.** Dotfuscator provides an option to disable such transforms.

After loading your Dotfuscator project in the GUI, this option can be found on the Settings tab, under "Advanced", named "Use only Mono-compatible transforms". Set this option to "Yes", then save and rebuild the project.

[image: Dotfuscator Professional Edition - Settings Tab, "Use only Mono-compatible transforms" enabled and highlighted]

If that is still giving you problems, you can disable Control Flow entirely to see if that fixes the problem. This is also on the Settings tab, under "Features", "Disable Control Flow". Set this option to "Yes", then save and rebuild the project.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Dotfuscator team at PreEmptive Solutions. If you have more questions, keep in mind that evaluation users like yourself also have full access to PreEmptive support*.

Comment: I did ask PreEmptive support team about this just after asking here. I had to add this stackoverflow link there because it was kind of difficult to write and quot all the code above in just a little box on the site. To my disappointment, he/she didn't even check this page I asked to have a look at. Moreover, he/she wrote only four short sentences just saying he/she wasn't sure why I couldn’t get it working because it should support Unity3d. But anyway, your answer from the same team here saved my day, thanks a million, Joe.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tested and that fixed the problem. And on top of that, when I turned on the option "Suppress Ildasm", it prevented ILDasm from opening the file perfectly! Very impressive, the best opfuscator of all time. Love it so much!

Comment: Sorry but could I ask two more quick questions? 1. Does the option "Suppress Ildasm" affect the performance? 2. Is there any tutorial on how to work with Unity3d?

Comment: The reason why I'm asking the second question is, when scrinpting in Unity3D directly, I'm wondering if there's a simple and easy way to apply Dotfuscator automatically before/after building an APK file. It only seems to be possible with standard C# DLL libraries but not Unity scripts which are all compiled and combined as "Assembly-CSharp.dll" on build.

Comment: 1) No, it applies the [SuppressIldasmAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.suppressildasmattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to the output assemblies, so there's no runtime performance impact.
2) I'm not familiar with Unity's workflow myself, but yes, Dotfuscator typically only applies to traditional C# assemblies.

Comment: Dotfuscator 6 didn't work for me with your guide. My Unity version is 2019.3.14f. Script backend is Mono.

Comment: @cloudending Dotfuscator [no longer supports Unity](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/dotfuscator-pro-change-log/1176) as of version 6.0. I'll update the answer with this information.

Comment: @JoeSewell Is there any way to download legacy version of Dotfuscator

Comment: @cloudending Registered users of Professional can still download prior versions by logging in to https://www.preemptive.com/downloads (click "Show previous versions..." for Dotfuscator).